# Navigation bar (bootstrap) taking space on top - Can I make it on top of my slider by default

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Probably pretty basic question but I'm having issues with it. I'm using bootstrap design for website that I'm making. By default, website didn't have any image sliders.

After adding in img slider, it appears that my navigation bar is always above it and never over the slider, which I don't like. Here's example:

This is how it looks at the moment when you load up the page
[image: How it looks at the moment]

And this is how I want it to look when you load the page (note that It works fine when i scroll down a bit)
[image]

So basicly my navigation works just fine, It's just not on top of the slider.

I'll include whole .css file that has everything, I linked an image to the slider and created navbar that sits on top (Opacity is 0.7).

I just want to make it sit on top of the slider at start and continue being on top of everything as I scroll (Note scrolling will not work in snippet). It works fine when scrolling just start position is what I'm having problems with.

Also don't worry about the blue stuff over the image in slider. It's WIP.

```css
.slider {
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 10px #9d9d9d;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 4px;
  
    
}

.slider ul {
  width: 1000%;
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  -moz-animation:slide-animation 5s infinite;
  -webkit-animation:slide-animation 25s infinite;
}


.slider li {
  width: 10%;
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

span.desc1 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 240px;
  width: 600px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 50px;
  bottom: 250px;
  left: 800px;
  padding: 0.5px 20px 0px 20px;
  margin-top: -450px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color:rgba(47, 118, 171, 0.7);
  color: #fcfcfc;
  font-family: "Roboto", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #9d9d9d;
  font-weight: normal;
  border-radius: 4px;
  z-index:2;
}

span.desc2 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 80px;
  width: 300px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0.5px 20px 0px 20px;
  margin-top: -450px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color:rgba(47, 118, 171, 0.6);
  color: #fcfcfc;
  font-family: "Roboto", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #9d9d9d;
  font-weight: normal;
  border-radius: 4px;
  z-index:2;
}

p.desc{
    color: #FFF;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide-animation {
  1% {left: 0%; opacity: 1;}
  18% {left: 0%; opacity: 1}
  19% {opacity: 0.2;}
  20% {left: -100%; opacity: 1;}
  58% {left: -100%; opacity: 1;}
  59% {opacity: 0.2;}
  60% {left: -200%; opacity: 1;}
  98% {left: -200%; opacity: 1;}
  99% {opacity: 0.5;}
  100% {left: 0%;}
}

@-moz-keyframes slide-animation {
  1% {left: 0%; opacity: 1;}
  18% {left: 0%; opacity: 1}
  19% {opacity: 0.2;}
  20% {left: -100%; opacity: 1;}
  58% {left: -100%; opacity: 1;}
  59% {opacity: 0.2;}
  60% {left: -200%; opacity: 1;}
  98% {left: -200%; opacity: 1;}
  99% {opacity: 0.5;}
  100% {left: 0%;}
}



h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  font-family: "Raleway", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

p {
  line-height: 1.55;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 400;
  font-family: "Raleway", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 62px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 65px;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 24px;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 18px;
}

/* ==================================================
  General
  ================================================== */
a {
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  -o-transition: 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

/* ==================================================
  Elements
  ================================================== */
.btn {
  background-color: #2f76ab;
  font-family: "Roboto", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 15px 45px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #E04F00;
  color: #fff;
}

.btn:focus {
  color: #fff;
}

.btn-ghost {
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.btn-ghost:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #2f76ab;
}

section {
  padding: 85px 0;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

.scrolltop {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 15px;
  right: 15px;
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #199EB8;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.scrolltop:hover, .scrolltop:active, .scrolltop:focus {
  color: #fff !important;
  opacity: .75;
}

/* ==================================================
  Hero Styling
================================================== */
.hero {
  display: table;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url(../img/cover.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 150px 0;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.hero:after {
  content: '';
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.hero .container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}

.hero-brand {
  margin-bottom: 75px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.hero-brand:hover {
  opacity: .75;
}

.tagline {
  font-family: "Raleway", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 26px;
  margin: 45px 0 75px 0;
  color: #fff;
}

/* ==================================================
  Header Styling
================================================== */
#header {
  background: rgba(47, 118, 171, 0.7);
  height: 70px;
}

#header #logo {
  margin: 14px 25px 0 0;
}

#header #logo h1 {
  font-size: 36px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2px 0;
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: "Raleway", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#header #logo h1 a, #header #logo h1 a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

#header #logo img {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  max-height: 40px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #header {
    height: 50px;
  }
  #header #logo {
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  }
  #header #logo h1 {
    padding: 2px 0;
    font-size: 26px;
  }
  #header #logo img {
    max-height: 30px;
  }
}

#header .social-nav {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

#header .social-nav a {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#header .social-nav a:hover {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
# Navigation Menu
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Nav Menu Essentials */
.nav-menu, .nav-menu * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  
}

.nav-menu ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}

.nav-menu li {
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.nav-menu > li {
  float: left;
}

.nav-menu li:hover > ul,
.nav-menu li.sfHover > ul {
  display: block;
}

.nav-menu ul ul {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
}

.nav-menu ul li {
  min-width: 180px;
}

/* Nav Menu Arrows */
.sf-arrows .sf-with-ul {
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.sf-arrows .sf-with-ul:after {
  content: "\f107";
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.sf-arrows ul .sf-with-ul:after {
  content: "\f105";
}

/* Nav Meu Container */
#nav-menu-container {
  margin: 0;
    
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #nav-menu-container {
    display: none;
  }
}

/* Nav Meu Styling */
.nav-menu a {
  padding: 22px 15px 18px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Roboto", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 15px;
  outline: none;
}

.nav-menu a:hover, .nav-menu li:hover > a, .nav-menu .menu-active > a {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
}

.nav-menu ul {
  margin: 4px 0 0 15px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}

.nav-menu ul li {
  background: #fff;
  border-top: 1px solid #f4f4f4;
}

.nav-menu ul li:first-child {
  border-top: 0;
}

.nav-menu ul li:hover {
  background: #199EB8;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  -o-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.nav-menu ul li a {
  color: #333;
  -webkit-transition: none;
  -o-transition: none;
  transition: none;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

.nav-menu ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.nav-menu ul ul {
  margin: 0;
}

/* Mobile Nav Toggle */
#mobile-nav-toggle {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  margin: 8px 10px 0 0;
  border: 0;
  background: none;
  font-size: 24px;
  display: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#mobile-nav-toggle i {
  color: #fff;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #mobile-nav-toggle {
    display: inline;
  }
}

/* ==================================================
  About styling
  ================================================== */
  
  
.about h2{
    color: #2f76ab;
}

img.tbasr{
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    margin: 10px;
    float: right;

}

img.tbasl{
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;

}



/* ==================================================
  Features Styling
  ================================================== */
.features {
  padding-bottom: 45px;
}

.features h2 {
  color: #2f76ab;
}

.features img {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;

}


/* Mobile Nav Styling */
#mobile-nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  padding-top: 18px;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 998;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  left: -260px;
  width: 260px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  -o-transition: 0.4s;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

#mobile-nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#mobile-nav ul li {
  position: relative;
}

#mobile-nav ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px 22px 10px 15px;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  outline: none;
}

#mobile-nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

#mobile-nav ul li li {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

#mobile-nav ul .menu-has-children i {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  padding: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
}

#mobile-nav ul .menu-has-children i.fa-chevron-up {
  color: #199EB8;
}

#mobile-nav ul .menu-item-active {
  color: #199EB8;
}

#mobile-body-overly {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 997;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  display: none;
}

/* Mobile Nav body classes */
body.mobile-nav-active {
  overflow: hidden;
}

body.mobile-nav-active #mobile-nav {
  left: 0;
}

body.mobile-nav-active #mobile-nav-toggle {
  color: #fff;
}

/* ==================================================
  Stats Styling
================================================== */
.stats-row {
  margin-top: 65px;
}

.stats-col .circle {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  font-family: "Raleway", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #666;
  border: 6px solid #2f76ab;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 55px 25px 0 25px;
  position: relative;
}

.stats-col .circle .stats-no {
  color: #fff;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  line-height: 70px;
  top: -25px;
  right: -15px;
  font-family: "Raleway", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: #E04F00;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-weight: 700;
}





/* ==================================================
  Call-to-action Styling
  ================================================== */
.cta {
  background-color: #2f76ab;
  padding: 25px 0;
}

.cta h2 {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.cta h2,
.cta p {
  color: #fff;
}

.cta p {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  opacity: .75;
}

.cta .btn-ghost {
  position: relative;
  top: 13px;
}

/* ==================================================
  Portfolio Styling
  ================================================== */
.portfolio {
  background-color: #edf6ff;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.portfolio h2 {
  color: #2f76ab;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.portfolio-grid {
  margin-top: 65px;
}

.portfolio-grid .row {
  margin: 0;
}

.portfolio-grid .row > div {
  padding: 0;
}

.portfolio-grid .row > div .card img {
  width: 100%;
}

.portfolio-grid .row > div .card .portfolio-over {
  position: absolute;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.portfolio-grid .row > div .card .portfolio-over > div {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.portfolio-grid .row > div .card .portfolio-over .card-title {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.portfolio-grid .row > div .card .portfolio-over .card-text {
  color: #fff;
  opacity: .75;
  padding: 0 45px;
}

.portfolio-grid .row > div .card:hover .portfolio-over {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.portfolio img{
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;

}

/* ==================================================
  Team Styling
  ================================================== */
.team h2 {
  color: #199EB8;
}

.team .col-sm-3 {
  padding: 0;
}

.team .card > a {
  display: block;
}

.team .card img {
  width: 100%;
}

.team .card h4 {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.team .card p {
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: .75;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 35px;
}

.team .card .social-nav {
  margin-bottom: 45px;
}

.team .card .social-nav a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0 4px;
}

.team .card .social-nav a:hover {
  opacity: .75;
}

.team .card:hover .team-over {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.team .card:hover .card-title-wrap {
  background-color: #199EB8;
}

.team .card:hover .card-title-wrap .card-title, .team .card:hover .card-title-wrap .card-text {
  color: #fff;
}

.team .team-over {
  padding-top: 45px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.team .card-title-wrap {
  padding: 15px 25px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.team .card-title-wrap .card-title, .team .card-title-wrap .card-text {
  font-family: "Raleway", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
}

.team .card-title-wrap .card-title {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #333;
}

.team .card-title-wrap .card-text {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #999;
}

/* ==================================================
  Contact Section
  ================================================== */
#contact {
  background: #f7f7f7;
  padding: 80px 0;
}

#contact h2 {
  font-family: "Raleway", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #199EB8;
}

#contact .info i {
  font-size: 32px;
  color: #199EB8;
  float: left;
}

#contact .info p {
  padding: 0 0 10px 50px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

#contact .form #sendmessage {
  color: #199EB8;
  border: 1px solid #199EB8;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#contact .form #errormessage {
  color: red;
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#contact .form #sendmessage.show, #contact .form #errormessage.show, #contact .form .show {
  display: block;
}

#contact .form .validation {
  color: red;
  display: none;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 13px;
}

#contact .form input, #contact .form textarea {
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

#contact .form button[type="submit"] {
  background: #199EB8;
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px 24px;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  -o-transition: 0.4s;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

#contact .form button[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: #23c2e1;
}

/* ==================================================
  Footer Styling
  ================================================== */
.site-footer {
  background-color: #111;
  padding: 0;
}

.site-footer h2, .site-footer p {
  color: #fff;
}

.site-footer p {
  opacity: .75;
  line-height: 2.0925;
}

.site-footer h2,
.site-footer .btn {
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.site-footer .social-nav a {
  color: #fff;
  opacity: .25;
}

.site-footer .social-nav a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.site-footer .bottom {
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.site-footer .bottom .list-inline, .site-footer .bottom p {
  margin: 0;
}

.site-footer .bottom .list-inline {
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
}

.site-footer .bottom .list-inline a {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Roboto", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.site-footer .bottom .list-inline a:hover {
  color: #199EB8;
}

.site-footer .credits {
  color: #ddd;
}

.site-footer .credits a {
  color: #199EB8;
}

/* ==================================================
  Responsive Styling
  ================================================== */
@media (max-width: 61.9em) {
  section,
  .block,
  .cta {
    padding: 35px 0;
  }
  .features {
    padding-bottom: 5px;
  }
  p,
  .block p {
    margin: 0;
  }
  .hero-brand {
    margin-bottom: 35px;
  }
  .tagline {
    margin: 35px 0;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 32px;
    margin: 0;
  }
  h2,
  .tagline {
    font-size: 24px;
  }
  h2 {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
  }
  h3 {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  .hero {
    padding: 75px 0;
  }
  .stats-col {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
  }
  .block {
    height: auto;
  }
  .feature-col {
    padding-bottom: 30px;
  }
  .portfolio-grid .card h3.card-title {
    font-size: 18px !important;
  }
  .portfolio-grid .card .card-text {
    font-size: 13px;
  }
  .team .team-over {
    padding-top: 20px;
  }
  .team .card .social-nav {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .site-footer .social-nav {
    margin-bottom: 35px;
  }
  .site-footer .list-inline {
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
  }
  .site-footer .list-inline li {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}



@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .block {
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Header -->
  <header id="header">
    <div class="container">
    
      <div id="logo" class="pull-left">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo-nav.png" alt="" title="" /></img></a>
      </div>
        
      <nav id="nav-menu-container">
        <ul class="nav-menu">
          <li><a href="#about"><?php echo $lang['nav_tbas']; ?></a></li>
          <li><a href="#features"><?php echo $lang['nav_hansaworld']; ?></a></li>
          <li><a href="#team"><?php echo $lang['nav_solutions']; ?></a></li>
          <li><a href="#portfolio"><?php echo $lang['nav_about']; ?></a></li>
          <!--<li class="menu-has-children"><a href="">Drop Down</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Drop Down 1</a></li>
              <li class="menu-has-children"><a href="#">Drop Down 2</a>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Deep Drop Down 1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Deep Drop Down 2</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Deep Drop Down 3</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Deep Drop Down 4</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Deep Drop Down 5</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Drop Down 3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Drop Down 4</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Drop Down 5</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>-->
          <li><a href="#contact"><?php echo $lang['nav_contact']; ?></a></li>
          <li><a href="http://ticket.sofido.net/login.php"><?php echo $lang['nav_support']; ?></a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <!-- #nav-menu-container -->
      
      <nav class="nav social-nav pull-right hidden-sm-down">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/SOFIDOgroup/"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a> 
        <a href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
  <!-- /header -->
    
    <!-- Slider -->

            <div class="slider">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <img src="http://www.sofido.net/img/slider/sofido-slide-01.jpg" />
                        <span class="desc1">
                            <p class="desc1"><div id="slide01">You are awesome<div></p>
                        </span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="http://www.sofido.net/img/slider/sofido-slide-01.jpg" />
                        <span class="desc2">
                            <h4><br />Another caption title</h4>
                            <p class="desc">More lorem ipsum dolor...</p>
                        </span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="http://www.sofido.net/img/slider/sofido-slide-01.jpg" />
                        <span class="desc">
                            <h4><br />Another caption title</h4>
                            <p class="desc">More lorem ipsum dolor...</p>
                        </span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    
    
   <!-- /Slider -->
```

Comment: I'd assume the position of the nav bar is set via javascript once you scroll. But you can try just setting position:fixed; top: 0; maybe it does the trick. Else you should check your Javascript.

Comment: Navigation bar is on top of the page regardless of that setting yes. The problem I'm having is that slider doesnt go "behind it" on top of the page, instead it just sits below the navbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `position: absolute` on `#header` will take it out of the static layout flow and the slider should "slide" up, so to say. You will also need to specify the width since it's out of the flow: `width: 100%` or `width: 100vw`should work. For good measure you should also add `top: 0` and `left: 0`.

You will probably need to set a `z-index` as well.

Note, I am not very familiar with Bootstrap and there might be a more "Bootstrap-way" to accomplish this, but it should work.

Also note, that I do not know if this will mess with the plugin, you use, that makes the header fixed.

Comment: So I added position, z-index, top and left atributes to #header in my main .css and this is what happens.

Default position (still above slider but this time in different shape):
https://image.prntscr.com/image/PvKxJpQ3S5qqgeBkZW4d0w.png

After I scroll just a bit down it becomes normal again:
https://image.prntscr.com/image/YKN2ha4XTLqGourDoLjUfQ.png

Comment: @David I have updated the answer. You need to add `width: 100%` or `width: 100vw` to `#header`.

Comment: That works just fine but if you check images that I included in my original question, I'm still having the same issue. My navigation bar is already on top of the page and that is not what I'm having issues with to be exact. The exact problem is that my slider just refuses to go straight to the top and behind navbar. If I decide to put absolute or fixed atribute to the slider then some other random stuff from my website is covering it instead just making it appear behind navbar at start. It's confusing problem

Comment: @David If you can provide an example through codepen or jsfiddle it will be easier to help you. I have a feeling that you have some javascript plugin that interferes with your css. An approach that probably works is to put `top: -70px` (the height of your navbar) on `.slider`, but it's a pretty hacky fix.

Comment: I tried using `top: -70px` attribute but that doesn't work either. Whole code is already in my top post. I'm not really a Javascript guy so if that is the problem then its bad..

Comment: Your JavaScript files are not in the top post. Neither is the `<head>` element. If you can link to the site or provide a live version some other way it will be infinitely easier to help you :)

Comment: Thing is that my slider is fully CSS, it might be the navbar javascript blocking the thing. I'll update post when I'm home and reply here when I do so